# sed squeeze multiple occurrence of word

Tags: bash, sed

I have text file with lines like below:

```
this is the code ;rfc1234;rfc1234
this is the code ;rfc1234;rfc1234;rfc1234;rfc1234
```

How can I squeeze the the repeating words in file to single word like below:

```
this is the code ;rfc1234
this is the code ;rfc1234
```

I tried 'tr' command but it's limited to squeezing characters only

Comment: If `sed 's/\(;[^;]*\).*/\1/'` isn't all you need then fix your example to be more truly representative of your real data.

Comment: @Ed your sed oneliner seems to work for my data, you can post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(;[^;]*\).*/\1/'  file
```

Comment: would you mind putting some more light on the expressions used?

Comment: Sure, it just repalces everything from the first semicolon-nonsemicolons string to the end of the line with that first string, thereby removing everything after the 2nd semi-colon inclusive.

Answer (score 3):

with `sed` for arbitrary repeated strings prefixed with `;`

```
$ sed -E 's/(;[^;]+)(\1)+/\1/g' file
```

or, if you want to delete everything after the first token without checking whether they match the preceding one or not

```
$ sed -E 's/(\S);.*/\1/' file
```

**Explanation**

> `(;[^;]+)` is to capture a string starting with semicolon
>   `(\1)+` followed by the same captured string one or more times
>   `/\1/g` replace the whole chain with one instance, and repeat

Comment: Could you please put some light on how this expression work

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help here. It will look for all items in last column of you Input_file and will keep only unique values in it.

```
awk '{num=split($NF,array,";");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){if(!array1[array[i]]++){val=val?val ";" array[i]:array[i]}};NF--;print $0";"val;val="";delete array;delete array1}'   Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
{
  num=split($NF,array,";");
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if(!array1[array[i]]++){
      val=val?val ";" array[i]:array[i]}
};
  NF--;
  print $0";"val;
  val="";
  delete array;
  delete array1
}'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '
{
  num=split($NF,array,";");             ##Creating a variable named num whose value is length of array named array, which is created on last field of line with ; as a delimiter.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                  ##Starting a for loop from i=1 to till value of num each time increment i as 1.
    if(!array1[array[i]]++){            ##Chrcking here a condition if array named array1 index is value of array[i] is NOT coming more than 1 value then do following.
      val=val?val ";" array[i]:array[i]}##Creating a variable named val here whose value is array[i] value and keep concatenating its own value of it.
};
  NF--;                                 ##Reducing the value of NF(number of fields) in current line to remove the last field from it.
  print $0";"val;                       ##Printing the current line(without last field) ; and then value of val here.
  val="";                               ##Nullifying variable val here.
  delete array;                         ##Deleting array named array here.
  delete array1                         ##Deleting array named array1 here.
}'  Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

I started playing around with `s/(.+)\1/\1/g`. It seemed to work with perl (even found the `is_is_`) but didn't quite take me there:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.+)\1+/\1/g' file
this the code ;rfc1234
this the code ;rfc1234;rfc1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to achieve this:-

```
 echo "this is the code ;rfc1234;rfc1234" | sed 's/rfc1234//2g'

 echo "this is the code ;rfc1234;rfc1234;rfc1234;rfc1234" | sed 's/rfc1234//2g'
```

or

```
  sed 's/rfc1234//2g' yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/(\S+)\1+/\1/g;ta' file
```

The regex is repeated until only the first pattern remains.